# Bean of SessionFactory cant be created. No definition Found

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

I am configuring spring mvc with hibernate 5 and i cant resolve this error. 
when i AutoWired sessionFactory its not creating bean.
I have been with this error for three days
i found that there is no need for autowiring sessionFactory. 
so i removed it, but how will it create the bean then, i tried that and it didnt worked.

```
ERROR [org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 77) Context initialization failed: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'userDaoImpl': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/security-config.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:598)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:90)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:376)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1377)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:575)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:498)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:848)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:865)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:548)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:400)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:291)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:103)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ApplicationListeners.contextInitialized(ApplicationListeners.java:187)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl$1.call(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:216)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl$1.call(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:185)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction$1.call(ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction.java:42)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ContextClassLoaderSetupAction$1.call(ContextClassLoaderSetupAction.java:43)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(SecurityContextThreadSetupAction.java:105)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1502)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1502)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1502)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1502)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl.deploy(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:250)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService.startContext(UndertowDeploymentService.java:96)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService$1.run(UndertowDeploymentService.java:78)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1982)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1486)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1377)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:485)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/security-config.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1744)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:576)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:498)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:273)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1241)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1168)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:595)
    ... 36 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:275)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:237)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:214)
    at org.hibernate.id.factory.internal.DefaultIdentifierGeneratorFactory.injectServices(DefaultIdentifierGeneratorFactory.java:152)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.injectDependencies(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:286)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:243)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:214)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.<init>(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:179)
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:119)
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.build(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:84)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataBuilderImpl.build(MetadataBuilderImpl.java:474)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataBuilderImpl.build(MetadataBuilderImpl.java:85)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:689)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:724)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean.buildSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:615)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:599)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1803)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1740)
    ... 46 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Access to DialectResolutionInfo cannot be null when 'hibernate.dialect' not set
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.dialect.internal.DialectFactoryImpl.determineDialect(DialectFactoryImpl.java:100)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.dialect.internal.DialectFactoryImpl.buildDialect(DialectFactoryImpl.java:54)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:137)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:35)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.initiateService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:94)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:263)
    ... 63 more

17:53:01,671 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 77) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.unit."Audit.war".undertow-deployment: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."Audit.war".undertow-deployment: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'userDaoImpl': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/security-config.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment]
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService$1.run(UndertowDeploymentService.java:81)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1982)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1486)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1377)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:485)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'userDaoImpl': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/security-config.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment]
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl.deploy(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:252)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService.startContext(UndertowDeploymentService.java:96)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService$1.run(UndertowDeploymentService.java:78)
    ... 8 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'userDaoImpl': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/security-config.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:598)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:90)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:376)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1377)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:575)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:498)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support
```

This is my pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.arthfc.audit</groupId>
  <artifactId>Audit</artifactId>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>Audit Maven Webapp</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
  <properties>
        <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
        <spring.version>5.1.0.RELEASE</spring.version>
        <hibernate.version>5.3.5.Final</hibernate.version>
        <hibernate.validator>5.4.1.Final</hibernate.validator>
        <c3p0.version>0.9.5.2</c3p0.version>
        <jstl.version>1.2.1</jstl.version>
        <tld.version>1.1.2</tld.version>
        <servlets.version>3.1.0</servlets.version>
        <jsp.version>2.3.1</jsp.version>
        <hsqldb.version>1.8.0.10</hsqldb.version>
    </properties>
  <dependencies>
  <!-- Spring MVC Dependency -->
     <dependency>
         <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
         <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
         <version>${spring.version}</version>
     </dependency>

     <!-- Spring ORM -->
     <dependency>
         <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
         <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
         <version>${spring.version}</version>
     </dependency>

     <!-- Hibernate Core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.17.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Hibernate Validator -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate.validator}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- JSTL Dependency -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp.jstl</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet.jsp.jstl-api</artifactId>
            <version>${jstl.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>taglibs</groupId>
            <artifactId>standard</artifactId>
            <version>${tld.version}</version>
        </dependency>

         <!-- Servlet Dependency -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>${servlets.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- JSP Dependency -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet.jsp-api</artifactId>
            <version>${jsp.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Commons DBCP -->
        <dependency>
           <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
           <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
           <version>1.4</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.47</version>
        </dependency>


    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
    <version>5.0.0.RELEASE</version>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
    <version>5.0.0.RELEASE</version>
  </dependency>



  <dependency>
       <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
       <artifactId>spring-security-taglibs</artifactId>
       <version>5.0.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>



    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.1</version> 
    </dependency>


  <dependency>
    <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.0</version>
  </dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.2</version>
 </dependency>
 <dependency>
     <groupId>javax.enterprise</groupId> 
     <artifactId>cdi-api</artifactId> 
     <version>1.2</version>
 </dependency>
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.reactivestreams</groupId>
   <artifactId>reactive-streams</artifactId>
   <version>1.0.1</version>
</dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <build>
    <finalName>Audit</finalName>
  </build>
</project>
```

dispatcher

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>  
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
   xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
   xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
   xsi:schemaLocation="
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc 
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd
   ">


   <context:component-scan base-package="com.audit" />
   <mvc:annotation-driven />

   <bean id="ViewResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix"> <value>/WEB-INF/views/</value></property>
        <property name="suffix"> <value>.jsp</value></property>
        <property name="order" value="2" />
   </bean>

   <bean id="propertyConfigurer"
        class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer"
        p:location="/WEB-INF/jdbc.properties">
    </bean>






    <!-- Custom Dao Beans -->
    <bean id="userDao" class="com.audit.daoImpl.UserDaoImpl"></bean>

    <!-- Custom Service Beans -->
    <bean id="userService" class="com.audit.serviceImpl.UserServiceImpl"></bean>







    <bean id="transactionManager"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"></property>
    </bean>
    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>


    <bean id="multipartResolver" class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver">
        <property name="maxUploadSize" value="10000000"/>
    </bean>

    <mvc:resources location="/WEB-INF/resources/css/" mapping="/resources/css/**" />
    <mvc:resources location="/WEB-INF/resources/js/" mapping="/resources/js/**" />
    <mvc:resources location="/WEB-INF/resources/gif/" mapping="/resources/gif/**" />
    <mvc:resources location="/WEB-INF/resources/images/" mapping="/resources/images/**" />
    <!--
    <bean class = "org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleMappingExceptionResolver">
       <property name = "exceptionMappings">
          <props>
             <prop key = "com.audit.controllers.*">
                ExceptionPage
             </prop>
          </props>
       </property>
       <property name = "defaultErrorView" value = "400"/>
    </bean>
 -->
</beans>
```

this is web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_4_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="4.0">

  <display-name>Audit</display-name>

  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>login</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>

  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>spring-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>
        org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
    </servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring-dispatcher-servlet.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>spring-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>

    <context-param>
         <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
         <param-value>/WEB-INF/security-config.xml </param-value>
    </context-param>

    <listener>
       <listener-class>
          org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
       </listener-class>
    </listener>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>
          org.springframework.security.web.session.HttpSessionEventPublisher
        </listener-class>
    </listener>

    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>1</session-timeout>
        <tracking-mode>COOKIE</tracking-mode>
    </session-config>

    <filter>    
      <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>    
      <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>    
     </filter>    

     <filter-mapping>    
      <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>    
      <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>    
     </filter-mapping>

     <servlet>

        <servlet-name>Spring MVC Dispatcher Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>classpath:applicationcontext.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
</web-app>
```

This is daoImpl

```
@Repository
@Transactional
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public class UserDaoImpl implements UserDao{

    private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(UserDaoImpl.class.getName());

    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;



    @Override
    public List<User> getUserList() {

        logger.info("sessionFactory " + sessionFactory);
        Criteria c = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createCriteria(User.class);
        ProjectionList p1 = Projections.projectionList();
        p1.add(Projections.property("userId"));

        c.setProjection(p1);

        List<?> list = c.list();

        List<User> uList = new ArrayList<User>();

        Iterator<?> it = list.iterator();

        while(it.hasNext()) {
            Object ob[] = (Object[])it.next();
            User u = new User();
            u.setUserId((String)ob[0]);
            uList.add(u);
        }


        return uList;
    }
```

This is hibernate.cfg.xml

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
    "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD//EN"
    "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <mapping class="com.audit.model.User"></mapping>
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

This is User Entity

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "USERS")
public class User {

private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(User.class.getName());

    @Id
    @Column(name = "USER_ID",length=60)
    private String userId;

    public String getUserId() {
        return userId;
    }

    public void setUserId(String userId) {
        this.userId = userId;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        builder.append("User [userId=").append(userId).append("]");
        return builder.toString();
    }
```

I changed my security-config.xml
this is my security-config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:sec="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-4.2.xsd
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

    <sec:http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true" >

        <sec:headers >
            <sec:cache-control />
            <sec:hsts/>
            <sec:frame-options />
        </sec:headers>

        <sec:csrf />

        <sec:form-login login-page="/login"
            login-processing-url="/authenticateUser" default-target-url="/connect"
            authentication-failure-url="/login" username-parameter="user"
            password-parameter="pass" />

        <sec:access-denied-handler error-page="/403"  />
        <sec:intercept-url pattern="/login" access="permitAll" />
        <sec:intercept-url pattern="/home" access="permitAll" />

        <sec:session-management invalid-session-url="/login" session-fixation-protection="migrateSession" >
            <concurrency-control   expired-url="/login" session-registry-alias="sessionRegistry"/>
        </sec:session-management>

        <sec:logout success-handler-ref="customLogoutSuccessHandler" invalidate-session="true" logout-url="/logout" />

    </sec:http>  

    <global-method-security  pre-post-annotations="enabled" />

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.audit" />

    <authentication-manager>
        <authentication-provider ref="customAuthenticationProvider" />
    </authentication-manager>
    <beans:bean id="customLogoutSuccessHandler" class="com.audit.LogoutHandler.CustomLogoutSuccessHandler" />
    <beans:bean id="dataSource"
        class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close"
        p:driverClassName="${jdbc.driverClassName}"
        p:url="${jdbc.databaseurl}" p:username="${jdbc.username}"
        p:password="${jdbc.password}">
     </beans:bean>

     <beans:bean id="sessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <beans:property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"></beans:property>

        <beans:property name="configLocation">
            <beans:value>classpath:hibernate.cfg.xml</beans:value>
        </beans:property>

        <beans:property name="hibernateProperties">
            <beans:props>
                <beans:prop key="hibernate.dialect">${jdbc.dialect}</beans:prop>
                <beans:prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</beans:prop>
                <beans:prop key="HBM2DDL_AUTO">update</beans:prop>
            </beans:props>
        </beans:property>
    </beans:bean>

</beans:beans>
```

Comment: Move the datasource and sessionfactory definitions to the `security-config.xml`.

Comment: Sir i moved it, and edited my code and also edited the errors, please have a look, the error is still coming

Comment: You need to set te dialect to use (as stated in the error message which I suggest you give a read).

Comment: thank you, this is my jdbc .properties `jdbc.driverClassName=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
jdbc.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
jdbc.databaseurl=jdbc:mysql://10.10.1.44/audit
jdbc.username=root
jdbc.password=****`

Comment: the connection is working

Comment: Without a propertyplaceholder element that isn't going to work. You need to move/copy that to your security context as well.

Comment: woaah its working, you are awesome. thank you

Comment: but why security-context.xml? can you please explain?

Comment: there are 2 application context one from the contextloaderlistener (the root context) the other is the one in the dispatcher-servlet (the servlet one, a child of the root context). Now as you are component-scanning in the security context and your `UserDaoImpl ` is annotated with `@Repository` is is already being detected. Actually with your current config you have 2 instances of that bean. You should move the transaction-manager and tx:annotation-driven as well to the security config.

Comment: i think i get it a bit. i will still keep searching for that. Thanks for helping.